# What is the fastest weapon to run with?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In *Counter-Strike: Global Offensive*, your running speed changes based on what weapon you hold. For example, holding a sniper rifle will cause you to run slowly, while holding a pistol will be much faster.

What is the fastest weapon to run with in the game?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuOy-5I1VcBMdGZmYndxUjctc1VNUDZHTXJFUE9Dbmc#gid=0

Comment: If you went through the tutorial, you would've had your answer

Comment: @Decency There are no Zeuses, Knives, or Grenades listed on that :P But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Retrosaur There's a tutorial?!?!

Comment: @avestar101 It's called "Weapons Course". Take it, it should introduce you to most aspects of the entire game.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A knife or a bomb.  Unless you wish to shoot, then a Tec 9 or Five Seven

**Terrorists**

```
Knife - 250 Velocity
Bomb - 250 Velocity
Grenades - 245 Velocity
Tec 9 - 245 Velocity
Glock - 240 Velocity
PP Bizon - 240 Velocity
Desert Eagle - 230 Velocity
UMP - 230 Velocity
P90 - 230 Velocity
Mac 10 - 225 Velocity
SG556 - 220 Velocity
MP7 - 220 Velocity
Scout - 220 Velocity
Nova - 220 Velocity
AK47 - 215 Velocity
AWP - 200 Velocity
M249 - 195 Velocity
```

**Counter Terrorists**

```
Knife - 250 Velocity
Grenades - 245 Velocity
Five Seven - 245 Velocity
P2000 - 240 Velocity
Glock - 240 Velocity
PP Bizon - 240 Velocity
MP9 - 240 Velocity
Desert Eagle - 230 Velocity
UMP - 230 Velocity
P90 - 230 Velocity
M4A1 - 225 Velocity
Mac 10 - 225 Velocity
AUG - 220 Velocity
MP9 - 220 Velocity
Scout - 220 Velocity
Nova - 220 Velocity
AWP - 200 Velocity
M249 - 195 Velocity
```

From [here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2591368)

Comment: I don't see a p250 or a CZ75 Auto anywhere on these charts, where do those guns stand?